# Find LSB/MSB values for voices in Yamaha CP5's MIDI implementation

Tags: midi, synthesizer

I got Yamaha CP5 and I try to define banks so that I can use its instruments from the computer (using the Rosegarden sequencer). Each bank should be specified by a MSB/LSB combination. The [data list](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Yamaha/CP5/Manual/152284) gives listing of all instruments, but it gives MSB/LSB values only for *performances* (combination of several parts, with different effects etc), not for *voices*:

[image: performance selection table]

Is there a way to access individual voices via MIDI? Likewise, is there a way to access drum banks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i'd just try sending some program change / bank msb control change / bank lsb control changes to it and see what shows up as the selected voice.
try 0, 0, 1;  then 0, 1, 0;  then 1, 0, 0;  eventually you should be able to figure it out.